# Get value from input text in same row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html-table

I've got this table with multiple rows. Each row contains 2 text input type fields and a button that runs a function on click.

Basically all of the input fields and buttons have the same id as they are appended with jQuery. Now I only want to pass the values of the text fields that are on the same row as the button. Does anybody now how I can do this?

```
 $("#teams").find('tbody')
        .append($('<tr>')

            .append($('<td>')
                .text(thisarray.matchId)
                .prop('id','matchId')
            )

            .append($('<td>')
                .text(thisarray.homeTeam)
            )
            .append($('<td>')
                .text(thisarray.awayTeam)
            )
            .append($('<td>')
                .append($('<input>')
                    .prop('type', 'text')
                    .prop('id', 'scoreHome')
                )
            )
            .append($('<td>')
                .append($('<input>')
                    .prop('type', 'text')
                    .prop('id', 'scoreAway')
                )
            )
            .append($('<td>')
                .append($('<input type="button" value="Ok" id="sendGoals"/>')
                )
            )
        );
```

This is the JS in one file.

```
function sendAllScores(){
//get scores
var scoreHomeTeam = $('#scoreHome').closest('tr').val();
var scoreAwayTeam = $('#scoreAway').closest('tr').val();
var matchId = $('#matchId').closest('tr').val();
```

And this from the other file

Comment: You should never use same ID among HTML elements..

Comment: we wont speculate.! please show some code..

Comment: Please post [**your code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are having issues with, accompanied by a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar), if required, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: `same id as they are appended with jquery` __IDs must be unique__

Comment: you should show your effort first

Comment: I know but I don't know how to do it otherwise. I tried creating the ID's are dynamically but then I didn't know how to get the elements in jquery.

Comment: To reiterate [IDs must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id). Use a className or a data-attribute if you want to use a common identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heres a small example for you: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/9Tn4P/)

populate this:

```
<table id="theTable"></table>
```

using this:

```
$(function(){
    var _rows=10;
    var _body="";
    for(i =0;i<_rows;i++){
        _body+="<tr>"+
            "<td><input type='text' class='text1'></input></td>"+
            "<td><input type='text' class='text2'></input></td>"+
            "<td><input type='button' class='theButton' value='Click Here'></input></td>"+
            "</tr>";
    }
    $("#theTable").html(_body);
    $(".theButton").on("click",function(){
        alert("Text1: "+$(".text1",$(this).parent().parent()).val()+", Text2: "+$(".text2",$(this).parent().parent()).val());
    });
 })
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need! However, when I try to do this in my own code it won't work. 
This is a small fiddle of what I've got. Don't know if you can do something with it. 

http://jsfiddle.net/u24ba/3/

Comment: your code works fine mate, you just forgot to close the `.on` function with `});`, and you need to select the jquery library on top left of the jsfiddle interface, here is a fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/u24ba/5/

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks so much for your help. I rewrote my code with your code and now I've got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If they're in same row. Then they must be inside the DOM like

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" /></td>
</tr>
```

If so, then the jQuery for that would be to go the parent row, and get the input value from it as

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
  var val = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').val();
  alert(val);
});
```

Note that there would be 2 parents,

1. td element
2. tr element.

Then you go to the child element of the input type and get its value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for id or something else. You can get em with indexes

```
$("table tr td input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
  var value1 = $(this).parent().parent().find("input:eq(0)").val();
  var value2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("input:eq(1)").val();
  // do your job with value1 and value2
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uA9QE/)